# Integer not returning as expected

Tags: c++

in my code below I am unsure as to why the function `decode char(char aChar)` is outputting `19 'x\13`, when inputted with '|' instead of `32`, as the `b` in `return b;` is `32` but the `data` in `decode(data)` is being read as `19 'x\13'`. The output of the nonworking function is '፼', where I would expect it to output ' '. When the code is put in directly without the `char decode(char aChar)` it all works fine, and as expected. What causes this is differ when it's own function and how may I fix this?

Comment: You edited the code out of your question? Have a downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not assigning the result of the function call

```
data = decode(data);
```